# Every prime bit must alternate

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source, primes, decision-problem, binary

A program is ***bit primed*** if bits in prime positions must alternate between zero and one, starting with one.

For example, this is a template for a bit primed program with [0..47] bits.

```
..10.1.0 ...1.0.. .1.0...1 .....0.1 .....0.. .1.0...1
01234567 89012345 67890123 45678901 23456789 01234567
```

---

**Create a bit primed program** that takes as input a string and checks if the string is bit primed. The string will be in ASCII and it will be a maximum of 1000 chars.

### Rules

- For the purposes of this challenge, the bit string for `ABCD` is

  ```
  01000001 01000010 01000011 01000100
  ```
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: @EasterlyIrk Modifying challenge

Comment: @EasterlyIrk little endian is trivial

Comment: Could you clarify what *Big Endian* refers to here? Do you mean the string itself, the individual bytes, or both?

Comment: @EasterlyIrk your code's "bits" are ordered in big endian when we tell if it's bit primed

Comment: @Dennis it is done

Comment: *your code's "bits" are ordered in big endian* That doesn't make any sense and you haven't answered my question.

Comment: @Dennis for every bit, if n is it's location and n is prime; bit will be 1 if the last was 0, 0 if the last was 1, 1 if n is 2. It matters the order of the individual bits.

Comment: *c'mon, I asked in chat before posting and in sandbox for 7 days*

Comment: I understand what you mean by alternating, just not how the bits are ordered. Please show us by example what bit string corresponds to the byte string `"ABCD"`. That should clear everything up.

Comment: @Dennis options, please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50760/discussion-between-dennis-and-nohtyyzar).

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/88806/56656).

Comment: @EasterlyIrk Completeness.

Comment: @EasterlyIrk see edit

Comment: @EasterlyIrk It was there before because the challenge objective was different, now it's unnecessary. [tag:status-completed]

Comment: @Alkali Only the 7 bit ASCII standard. String is null-terminated if your language requires it.

Comment: I've spent several hours trying to come up with a JavaScript solution, but fitting a function name of more than 3 characters in is terrible. Either way, a few testcases for bit-prime strings would be nice.

Comment: @RomanCzyborra I don't care if you're proving a point, please don't make a massive comment of mostly nonsense characters. Next please say something like "Here is a counterexample @ Wheat Wizard: <pastebin link>".

Comment: I propose this Python3 program to generate such strings: http://pastebin.com/5iXPx2su

Comment: You should probably make it so that if the program does not consist of only ASCII, then it should support input of whatever code page it's encoded in.

Comment: To see a set of allowed characters for each position in your code: [Python program](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#fZAxT8MwEIXn@FecjJBsakVJGCgBsyAxwgKTFaGkdemh1Am2kfj35ZxEKurAdhe/9@7LO@JhHHyEQxv3CrxlW7sDDO@jx4MVTtYswx04uIcKBk/DJQ1aQwGt29L6AFVNtvjtHTy1fbAsW7a270WSI@zIiIAOfOs@rLhWNEeRLubhy0e6ImEFpYJKSsYeX96eX0FDVbAJItBs/oT8zCmz7ArWEvAPMcqGJUePIQrDcz69ghti8i6BljiBl/yf0IZIOl2wc0VvnQhyqSUYbLSmIFrT3tXTF17wu@TNsnSo7nQ5IRnO888ByW@wxtW6kefNFArmfJUIGLsgXhchsAljPAlPFLNiVGaz9/Tzp0Rzq8qiWS2VV6qsbqamvM2p@c2eKMZGJT2tAhXwYt1xSWfnzOPxFw).

Answer (score 11):

## Mathematica, 5432 bytes

```
f[gQqGCStZu2yl3mIEL5mBpO43ulpBaJP4g2sCvYht09xS9XvYv2XK7aZ6P2yh47J2y2Z8s42u91aKQT8dDQ7NZQFDShTWXW7ldVB8IorrV2Fu6ItvMF2y285nz52GizM3X1q0t3F7KMa@Print[29RshFOc0Zh3HKaau;i=0;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;AllTrue[XF2uhxta8qS5K0ZeL9pmX3Zhrqn4IHD2hNTdEb9rsQw8raVJvbgSP1uk9OByu;Pick[l=(2EOFI4khaVxpn5d01z8kaARZNiz1oNZkcniL0sD13Sfqrapri0sq9AV12Wh9F1NtYjwbvHtM73G;Join@@(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;IntegerDigits[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;ToCharacterCode@#,wm;2,Yr3TLDuNJKQ2NHCv9;8])),hmPvHeg3R2mw02;Array[yruQ95uaGFdJu1;PrimeQ,Tr[GjbUXt;0l+1],Xxt;0]],8La1ktK9xi3XXf;#==(UISzsyNOrrXj0eSRMrbIzDOVjfKK0IazH6JdZQY7lzBolXGwU98mJjINCzp7pROIx1rwaTo1JdOSyw6Lw3KVXu85AxiKM7Q2EsvUEQaq8rMhAwdsgWYO21aAVLwuoz5Uz8NnASPJmW4f04z1kgUrAfMjZ0VAFaM2405222oU3y0yc5nxVmKd7AcA5gwCa3labMkKF7lMq5o8prUSy1AVTxNH7E46LVYWjxyw6Q6YRzNPSRJJWtjhVGt8tMkj;i=1-i)&]]Df]&
```

Takes a string as an input. Prints `True` or `False`. This works because Mathematica ignores undefined variables/functions. Because this code is so long, I stuck some easter eggs in there. :)

I'm sure this can be golfed more...

**Explanation**

Without all the gibberish (99 bytes):

```
AllTrue[Pick[l=Join@@IntegerDigits[ToCharacterCode@#,2,8],Array[PrimeQ,Tr[0l+1],i=0]],#==(i=1-i)&]&
```

---

```
ToCharacterCode@#
```

Convert the input into character codes.

```
IntegerDigits[ToCharacterCode@#,2,8]
```

Convert the character codes into binary numbers, length 8.

```
l=Join@@IntegerDigits[ToCharacterCode@#,2,8]
```

Flatten the result and store that in `l`. This generates the bit list of the input.

---

```
Tr[0l+1]
```

A short way to find the length of `l`.

```
Array[PrimeQ,Tr[0l+1],i=0]
```

Set `i` to 0. Create a list from 0 to (length l) - 1. Map primality test onto that list. In this list, only the prime positions are `True`.

---

```
Pick[l=Join@@...,Array[...]]
```

From the first argument (bit list), select ones whose corresponding element of the second argument (list whose prime positions are `True`) is `True`.

```
AllTrue[Pick[...],#==(i=1-i)&]
```

Check whether the resulting list is alternating 1 and 0, starting with 1. (each element is compared to `i`, and `i` alternates between 1 and 0 (`i=1-i`) each iteration).

**Testing**

```
f[gQqGCStZu2yl3mIEL5mBpO43ulpBaJP4g2sCvYht09xS9XvYv2XK7aZ6P2yh47J2y2Z8s42u91aKQT8dDQ7NZQFDShTWXW7ldVB8IorrV2Fu6ItvMF2y285nz52GizM3X1q0t3F7KMa@Print[29RshFOc0Zh3HKaau;i=0;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;AllTrue[XF2uhxta8qS5K0ZeL9pmX3Zhrqn4IHD2hNTdEb9rsQw8raVJvbgSP1uk9OByu;Pick[l=(2EOFI4khaVxpn5d01z8kaARZNiz1oNZkcniL0sD13Sfqrapri0sq9AV12Wh9F1NtYjwbvHtM73G;Join@@(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;IntegerDigits[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;ToCharacterCode@#,wm;2,Yr3TLDuNJKQ2NHCv9;8])),hmPvHeg3R2mw02;Array[yruQ95uaGFdJu1;PrimeQ,Tr[GjbUXt;0l+1],Xxt;0]],8La1ktK9xi3XXf;#==(UISzsyNOrrXj0eSRMrbIzDOVjfKK0IazH6JdZQY7lzBolXGwU98mJjINCzp7pROIx1rwaTo1JdOSyw6Lw3KVXu85AxiKM7Q2EsvUEQaq8rMhAwdsgWYO21aAVLwuoz5Uz8NnASPJmW4f04z1kgUrAfMjZ0VAFaM2405222oU3y0yc5nxVmKd7AcA5gwCa3labMkKF7lMq5o8prUSy1AVTxNH7E46LVYWjxyw6Q6YRzNPSRJJWtjhVGt8tMkj;i=1-i)&]]Df]&["f[gQqGCStZu2yl3mIEL5mBpO43ulpBaJP4g2sCvYht09xS9XvYv2XK7aZ6P2yh47J2y2Z8s42u91aKQT8dDQ7NZQFDShTWXW7ldVB8IorrV2Fu6ItvMF2y285nz52GizM3X1q0t3F7KMa@Print[29RshFOc0Zh3HKaau;i=0;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;AllTrue[XF2uhxta8qS5K0ZeL9pmX3Zhrqn4IHD2hNTdEb9rsQw8raVJvbgSP1uk9OByu;Pick[l=(2EOFI4khaVxpn5d01z8kaARZNiz1oNZkcniL0sD13Sfqrapri0sq9AV12Wh9F1NtYjwbvHtM73G;Join@@(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;IntegerDigits[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;ToCharacterCode@#,wm;2,Yr3TLDuNJKQ2NHCv9;8])),hmPvHeg3R2mw02;Array[yruQ95uaGFdJu1;PrimeQ,Tr[GjbUXt;0l+1],Xxt;0]],8La1ktK9xi3XXf;#==(UISzsyNOrrXj0eSRMrbIzDOVjfKK0IazH6JdZQY7lzBolXGwU98mJjINCzp7pROIx1rwaTo1JdOSyw6Lw3KVXu85AxiKM7Q2EsvUEQaq8rMhAwdsgWYO21aAVLwuoz5Uz8NnASPJmW4f04z1kgUrAfMjZ0VAFaM2405222oU3y0yc5nxVmKd7AcA5gwCa3labMkKF7lMq5o8prUSy1AVTxNH7E46LVYWjxyw6Q6YRzNPSRJJWtjhVGt8tMkj;i=1-i)&]]Df]&"]
```

> `True`

Feeding the program to itself does print `True`.

```
f[gQqGCStZu2yl3mIEL5mBpO43ulpBaJP4g2sCvYht09xS9XvYv2XK7aZ6P2yh47J2y2Z8s42u91aKQT8dDQ7NZQFDShTWXW7ldVB8IorrV2Fu6ItvMF2y285nz52GizM3X1q0t3F7KMa@Print[29RshFOc0Zh3HKaau;i=0;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;AllTrue[XF2uhxta8qS5K0ZeL9pmX3Zhrqn4IHD2hNTdEb9rsQw8raVJvbgSP1uk9OByu;Pick[l=(2EOFI4khaVxpn5d01z8kaARZNiz1oNZkcniL0sD13Sfqrapri0sq9AV12Wh9F1NtYjwbvHtM73G;Join@@(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;IntegerDigits[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;ToCharacterCode@#,wm;2,Yr3TLDuNJKQ2NHCv9;8])),hmPvHeg3R2mw02;Array[yruQ95uaGFdJu1;PrimeQ,Tr[GjbUXt;0l+1],Xxt;0]],8La1ktK9xi3XXf;#==(UISzsyNOrrXj0eSRMrbIzDOVjfKK0IazH6JdZQY7lzBolXGwU98mJjINCzp7pROIx1rwaTo1JdOSyw6Lw3KVXu85AxiKM7Q2EsvUEQaq8rMhAwdsgWYO21aAVLwuoz5Uz8NnASPJmW4f04z1kgUrAfMjZ0VAFaM2405222oU3y0yc5nxVmKd7AcA5gwCa3labMkKF7lMq5o8prUSy1AVTxNH7E46LVYWjxyw6Q6YRzNPSRJJWtjhVGt8tMkj;i=1-i)&]]Df]&["$;A;;A;;>@??A/??/@>?/;;?>??>;@@/@"]
```

> `True`

Checking `"$;A;;A;;>@??A/??/@>?/;;?>??>;@@/@"` -- `True`.

```
f[gQqGCStZu2yl3mIEL5mBpO43ulpBaJP4g2sCvYht09xS9XvYv2XK7aZ6P2yh47J2y2Z8s42u91aKQT8dDQ7NZQFDShTWXW7ldVB8IorrV2Fu6ItvMF2y285nz52GizM3X1q0t3F7KMa@Print[29RshFOc0Zh3HKaau;i=0;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;AllTrue[XF2uhxta8qS5K0ZeL9pmX3Zhrqn4IHD2hNTdEb9rsQw8raVJvbgSP1uk9OByu;Pick[l=(2EOFI4khaVxpn5d01z8kaARZNiz1oNZkcniL0sD13Sfqrapri0sq9AV12Wh9F1NtYjwbvHtM73G;Join@@(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;IntegerDigits[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;ToCharacterCode@#,wm;2,Yr3TLDuNJKQ2NHCv9;8])),hmPvHeg3R2mw02;Array[yruQ95uaGFdJu1;PrimeQ,Tr[GjbUXt;0l+1],Xxt;0]],8La1ktK9xi3XXf;#==(UISzsyNOrrXj0eSRMrbIzDOVjfKK0IazH6JdZQY7lzBolXGwU98mJjINCzp7pROIx1rwaTo1JdOSyw6Lw3KVXu85AxiKM7Q2EsvUEQaq8rMhAwdsgWYO21aAVLwuoz5Uz8NnASPJmW4f04z1kgUrAfMjZ0VAFaM2405222oU3y0yc5nxVmKd7AcA5gwCa3labMkKF7lMq5o8prUSy1AVTxNH7E46LVYWjxyw6Q6YRzNPSRJJWtjhVGt8tMkj;i=1-i)&]]Df]&["ABC"]
```

> `False`

Checking `ABC` -- `False`

**Check for characters that work**

```
Catch[Block[
   {p, j = 1, i = 0, c = Characters@#, l, k = #2 - 1, max = 100000},
   p = AssociationMap[(i = 1 - i) &, Prime~Array~max];
   l = Length@c;
   While[k < max/8,
    Which[j > l,
       Throw[k - l + 1],
       MatchQ[IntegerDigits[ToCharacterCode[c[[j]]][[1]], 2, 8], #],
       j++,
       j > 1,
       k -= j - 1; j = 1
       ] &@Array[Lookup[p, #, _] &, 8, 8 k];
    k++
    ]; $Failed]] &
```

I wrote a simple code that checked where certain characters could be inserted (e.g. the first place to put `Print[` while keeping the code bit-primed is position 141, 1-indexed).

The first argument is the string in interest and the second argument is the starting position (also 1-indexed).

I used this code to find out where to put meaningful code and then filled the rest of the code with gibberish, but choosing characters that keep the code bit-primed; simple with `Prime` and `Partition` (and `RandomChoice`)

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is a perfectly good answer, just very long...

Comment: @ev3commander my original answer was not a bit-primed program.

Comment: @JungHwanMin I see my problem now; I was one-indexing the first byte. With the first byte zero-indexed, the first bit of any byte is always on an even index.

Comment: `WhatALongProgram`